# Increase the background image size as per content

Tags: css

Look at the image below

[image: pagination]

I'm developing the pagination. As per image above the pagination contents, the page number should be surrounded by the the fancy border, such border is not possible through css `border`property. I have to use image for this, but the problem is if I use a fixed size background image then as when number of pages increases they will be displayed outside that background image.

How do  I go so that background image should also increase with the number of pages.

I hope this make sense.

Comment: its possible with   border-radius
http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius

Comment: @SRN: that it is not a cross browser support. IE8 does not support it

Comment: you can look at curvycorners http://code.google.com/p/curvycorners/

Comment: @Daric You can probably fix that with the script at css3pie.com if your comfortable with that. Makes border-radius work in IE.

Comment: @Daric Or you can have the left piece of the border as an image and the right piece as an image. Make them backgrounds of an element on the most left and right side. Then have the element in the middle repeat a small image with only the top and bottom side of the border.

Comment: @Noik: Do I have to use 3 html elements for this?

Comment: @Daric see easwee's answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options - doing it with `border-radius` or using a `background-image`.

If you gonna use border-radius (note it is not supported in IE8 and older):

.pager-container {border-radius:5px 0 5px 0;border:1px solid #ccc;}

If you use `background-image` you first need to create a sprite for your background (the one below will extend up to 800px).

[image: Background image sprite]

Now that you have your sprite you will need to wrap your paging in 2 wrappers and apply the sprite image to both and just move it with `background-position` to put it in place:

```
<div class="pager-container">
<div class="pager-container-inner">
   <a>1></a>
</div>
</div>

.pager-container, .pager-container-inner {height:25px;background-image:url(sprite.gif);background-repeat:no-repeat;}
.pager-container {background-position:0 0}
.pager-container-inner {background-position:100% -25px;}
```